# Difference between 'Klimawandel' and 'Klimaänderung'

Tags: word-usage

I know both of them means Climate change but I want to know when either of them is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Klimaänderung describes a specific change (eg. temperature) or a few things that change which could also happen in a sauna.

Klimawandel means the thing that is happening to our world.

Answer (score 7):

The word used usually in German is "Klimawandel". While "Klimaänderung" transports the same meaning "Klimawandel" simply is the established term.

Comment: I think it is worth noting, that "Klimawandel" is somewhat politically loaded (related to the greenhouse effect), whereas "Klimaänderung" seems to be more a neutral word to describe climate changes, which could be caused by anything else.

Comment: @BarthZalewski That's *currently* the case, but only because one is the term commonly used in the controversial debates, and the other isn't. A few years back "globale Erwärmung" was loaded and "Klimawandel" wasn't yet.